# GitLab - test coverage histrory / trend

Tags: charts, continuous-integration, gitlab, code-coverage

I use Gitlab CI t report Code Coverage. The CI script prints the output to the console which is then fetched by GitLab via regular expression.

As the result, I get the following coverage description in every merge request:

[image: pipeline passed image]

The question is - how can I track the trend (or change) of this value over a period of time.

I'd like to show the chart with coverage change for e.g. last month, so I'd see, whether the project's code quality is improved or decreased. Looking to something similar to this image:

[image: code coverage chart]

**Which GitLab plugins or open source tools allow to get such a picture / report? Is it possible to achieve a similar result by using just gitlab alone?**

Comment: You can do a GET request to the pipeline API https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines then extract the coverages then use something like https://www.image-charts.com/ for the static image part :)

Comment: nice, but I'm looking to out-of-the-box solution